# Delete an ini file's section and its data VB.NET/C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, ini

How can I delete an ini file's section and its data in VB.NET?
Actually, I can delete only data but not the title of the section.

```
      rivate Declare Ansi Function WritePrivateProfileString _
      Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
      (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
      ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, _
      ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
```

Comment: Is it a plane text file? XML? Jason? What is the format of file? U want it in VB or c# or doesn't matter? U see u getting a lot of down votes if u don't give more details. Also show what u already did. Some code would be nice.

Comment: i use a plane text file in VB or C#. i think that my post is clear, any developer can understand it, i dont undersatnd why i have a down vote.

Comment: Not from me but perhaps u got it before adding formatting to your code. Stackoverflow tends to be a rough place :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [WritePrivateProfileSection](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WritePrivateProfileSection.html).

To clear the entire section pass NULL for the lpString parameter.

*edit:*

Tested code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function WritePrivateProfileSection(ByVal lpAppName As String, ByVal lpString As IntPtr, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function WritePrivateProfileString(ByVal lpAppName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Boolean
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim res As Boolean
        res = WritePrivateProfileString("Test", "val1", "1", "D:\test.ini")
        res = WritePrivateProfileString("Test", "val2", "1", "D:\test.ini")
        res = WritePrivateProfileString("Test", "val3", "1", "D:\test.ini")

        res = WritePrivateProfileString("Test1", "val1", "1", "D:\test.ini")
        res = WritePrivateProfileString("Test1", "val2", "1", "D:\test.ini")
        res = WritePrivateProfileString("Test1", "val3", "1", "D:\test.ini")

        res = WritePrivateProfileSection("Test", IntPtr.Zero, "D:\test.ini")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: i pass this    WritePrivateProfileString(sectionName, Nothing, Nothing, Me.path)
    End Sub.  i have always the section.

Comment: I said Section, not String.

Look at the page i linked.

Comment: In that case you are doing it wrong, i just tested here and it works fine.
If you want more help, provide code since i lost my mindreading device a while ago.