# C#: What is the easiest way to delete a Section and its Keys from an INI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ini

I have an INI file that consists of multiple Sections, and a single key named "Path". Everything in the INI is loaded into a DataGridView on Load for manipulating the contents of the file.

```
INI Example:
[First Entry]
Path=C:\test1.txt
[Second Entry]
Path=C:\test2.txt
[Third Entry]
Path=C:\test3.text
```

What would be the easiest possible method of deleting [Second Entry] that wouldn't wipe out the entire file?

Here's what I'm working with at the moment for Writing new info to the file:

```
INI Class:
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string val, string fileName);

public void Write(string section, string key, string value)
{
WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value.ToLower(), path);
}

Form Button:
private void WriteINI()
{
myINI.Write(txtName.Text, "Path", txtPath.Text);
ReadINI();
}
```

Comment: Easily convertible to C#: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31671066/3740093

Comment: Load it into a data structure and only write back the fields you want to keep.

Comment: Have you considered using a library to handle ini files? I've created one: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser  (can be installed with NuGet)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`WritePrivateProfileString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-writeprivateprofilestringa?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method you can delete the entire section by passing null value for `lpKeyName` to  method this way:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WritePrivateProfileString(
       string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, string lpString,string lpFileName);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WritePrivateProfileString("Second Entry", null, null, @"d:\test.ini");
}
```

> [**lpKeyName**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-writeprivateprofilestringa?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
>   The name of the key to be associated with a string. If
>   the key does not exist in the specified section, it is created. If
>   this parameter is NULL, the entire section, including all entries
>   within the section, is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

How about going through it yourself? Something on those lines:

```
private static void RemoveSectionFromIniFile(string file, string section)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        using (var writer = File.CreateText(file + ".tmp"))
        {
            var i = false;
            while (reader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
                    {
                        if (i) i = false;
                        else if (line.Substring(1, line.Length - 2).Trim() == section) i = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!i) writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
    File.Delete(file);
    File.Move(file + ".tmp", file);
}
```

Lacks exception and format handling but does the job.

Comment: Surely it's better to avoid such text processing while you can simply delete the entire section using `WritePrivateProfileString` by passing null to `lpKeyName` parameter.